# Can I submit a form using jquery/ajax to a php script that returns a file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP script that is using PHPExcel. It generates an xlsx file for download. However, this takes quite a bit of time depending on the paramters that the users selects. I am wondering if I can submit the paramaters to via ajax, show a "loader" image after submitting it, but once the file is complete, return the file for download.

Here is what I tried, but it didn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) { 
    $("#reporting-export-form").submit(function(e) {
        $("#loadingImage").show();
        var url = "reporting-export-download.php";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $("#reporting-export-form").serialize(),
            success: function(data)
            {
                return data;
                $("#loadingImage").hide();
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }); 
});
```

**UPDATE**
So I think the consenhsious is that it cant' be done. So I have another idea that is working 99% and fakes an ajax experience, but with 1 glitch. I put an iframe on the page. I then set the target of my form to be that iframe. When it submits, the page stays on it's current page and when the PHPExcel file finishes it presents the file for download. So then I added this jQuery code to my page:

```
$("#reporting-export-form").submit(function(e) {
    $("#loadingImage").show();
});
```

And that works great as well. Now I want to hide the loading image once the file is either downloaded or cancelled. So I added this code to the page that outputs the file:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('#loadingImage', window.parent.document).hide();
});
```

That doesn't work. If I remove the PHP code that outputs the file, then it does remove the loading image after the iframe loads, but as long as I try to output the php file in the iframe, the javascript doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Ajax can not do this downloading ...

Comment: The issue is that the PHPExcel file generated by the server gets captured by the `data` variable in $.ajax.success. When you `do return data;` it doesn't send the file to the browser for download, it passes it to the calling function (somewhere in JQuery).

One approach would be to have a javascript controlled link which shows the loading image and redirects the browser to the PHPExcel generating page.

Comment: Please see my update with my new idea.